# Scrapy + Splash = Connection Refused

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I installed **Splash** using this [link](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html).
Followed all steps to installation, but Splash doesn't work.

My **settings.py** file:

```
BOT_NAME = 'Teste'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['Test.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'Test.spiders'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
     'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
     'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725, 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,}
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
SPLASH_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8050/'
```

When I run `scrapy crawl TestSpider`:

```
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.google.com.br via http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.google.com.br via http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.google.com.br via http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 3 times): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
[scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.google.com.br via http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.html>
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/home/ricardo/scrapy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1126, in _inlineCallbacks
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
File "/home/ricardo/scrapy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
File "/home/ricardo/scrapy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request 
defer.returnValue((yield 
download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused 
by other side: 111: Connection refused.
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
[scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 3, 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError': 3,
'downloader/request_bytes': 1476,
'downloader/request_count': 3,
'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 3,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 29, 21, 36, 16, 72916),
'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
'log_count/ERROR': 1,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
'memusage/max': 47468544,
'memusage/startup': 47468544,
'retry/count': 2,
'retry/max_reached': 1,
'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError': 2,
'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
'splash/render.html/request_count': 1,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 29, 21, 36, 15, 851593)}
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Here is my **spider**:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class TesteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="Teste"

    def start_requests(self):
            yield SplashRequest("http://www.google.com.br", self.parse, meta={"splash": {"endpoint":"render.html",}})

    def parse(self, response):
            self.log('Hello World')
```

I tried to run this in terminal: `curl http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http://www.google.com/"`

**Output:**

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8050: Connection Refused

Comment: Are you using Docker? What command are you using to run Splash? What is your OS? What is your Docker version?  If you can't access Splash on http://localhost:8050 then likely Docker uses a different host, or maybe you forgot to expose 8050 port.

Comment: I'm not using Docker, but using Venv in Ubuntu 16.04.
Is it necessary uses Docker?

Comment: It is not necessary to use Docker, but it is the easiest way to install Splash. You can install it to virtualenv, but it is harder. How are you starting SPlash - could you paste the exact command? Are you sure Splash is running?

Comment: Thank you @MikhailKorobov!!! Much easier to use Docker.

Answer (score 6):

You need run via command line:

```
sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
```

And settings.py as

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'
```

Answer (score 5):

please make sure your splash server is up and running before calling the spider.

`sudo docker run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 scrapinghub/splash`